# Make tabs appear when bars icon is clicked(responsive navbar)

Tags: html, css

I created a navbar and all the tabs are inline. When the window size is reduced, a bars icon appears and the tabs display vertically instead of horizontally. I want the output so that when the window size is reduced, the bars icon appears but the tabs disappear and can only be seen (vertically) and unseen when the bars icon is clicked.
I tried jquery, but it didn't work. I'm not sure how to do this, can you help me?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

nav {
  margin-left: 45px;
  ;
  width: 90%;
  background: #D1D0D3;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
}

ul a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  background-color: #C2ABF1;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .block {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <i class="fa fa-bars menu" id="menu"></i>
</div>
<nav>
  <ul class="ul">
    <li class="block"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="block"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="block"><a href="#">Makeup</a></li>
    <li class="block"><a href="#">Hairstyle</a></li>
    <li class="block"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this jquery code

```
$(".menu").on("click", function() {
  $("nav .ul").toggle(500);
})
```

And this CSS in media query

```
.ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
      margin-left: 0;
      width: 100%;
  }
```

```js
$(".menu").on("click", function() {
  $("nav .ul").toggle(500);
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

nav {
  margin-left: 45px;
  ;
  width: 90%;
  background: #D1D0D3;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
}

ul a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  background-color: #C2ABF1;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .block {
    display: block;
  }
  .ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eed659c9d4.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">
  <i class="fa fa-bars menu" id="menu"></i>
</div>
<nav>
  <ul class="ul">
    <li class="block"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="block"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="block"><a href="#">Makeup</a></li>
    <li class="block"><a href="#">Hairstyle</a></li>
    <li class="block"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Your code should be like this:

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
     body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Sans-Serif;
    }
    nav{
      margin-left: 45px;;
      width: 90%;
      background: #D1D0D3;
    }

    ul{
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      color: black;
      padding: 0;

    }

    ul a {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li{
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 20px;

    }

    ul li:hover{
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .toggle{
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
      background-color: #C2ABF1;
      text-align: right;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      color: white;
      font-size: 30px;
      display: none;
    }

    @media (max-width: 800px)
    {
      .toggle{
        display: block;
      }

      nav ul{
        display:none;
      }

      ul li{
        display:block;
      }
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="toggle">
      <i class="fa fa-bars menu" id="menu"></i>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul class="ul">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Makeup</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hairstyle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

</body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".menu").on("click", function() {
      $("nav .ul").toggle();
    })
</script>

</html>
```